Financial Time-Series: Stochastic or Dynamic?
I have learned how some methods of constructing predictive models of financial time-series involves assumptions of stochasticity. For example, reinforcement learning utilizes the Markov Decision Process (MDP) which is meant to model a stochastic system.
However, from my perspective, financial time-series are more accurately defined as dynamical systems in that they are the product of complex interplaying factors from past and present that are constantly changing the system.
This is because, in reality, the stock price isn't truly random (stochastic), its price fluctuations are just so complex that it is easier to chalk it up to randomness (in my opinion).
Is the reason we can use MDP because the financial time-series is so complex that it may as well be a stochastic system?
Is there something else that I am misunderstanding?
Thank you!

If one factor is a random variable this will render the stock price a random variable as well...
